# How to merge two files?

Tags: json, file, merge, jq

I am trying to merge the files using --argjson but it throws

> argument list too long

Is there any other way I can merge these files?

Tried to use --slurpfile but can't get desired output

```
[
  {
    "path": "1"
  },
  {
    "path": "a/1"
  },
  {
    "path": "a/2"
  }
]
```

```
jq --argjson groupInfo "$(jq .data file1.json)" '.records[].version.data+=$groupInfo' file2.json
```

File 1:

```
{
    "id": "test",
    "data": [
        {
            "path": "a/1"
        },
        {
            "path": "a/2"
        }
    ],
    "information": {
        "id": "1"
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "version": {
        "data": [
            {
                "path": "1"
            }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output File:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "version": {
        "data": [
          {
            "path": "1"
          },
          {
            "path": "a/1"
          },
          {
            "path": "a/2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--arg` and `--argjson` options are intended for small bits of JSON. Although the `--argfile` option is technically deprecated, it fits nicely here with your approach:

```
jq --argfile groupInfo <(jq .data file1.json) '
  .records[].version.data+=$groupInfo' file2.json
```

There are other options. E.g.

```
jq -s '
  .[0].data as $groupInfo
  | .[1]
  | .records[].version.data+=$groupInfo
' file1.json file2.json
```

I'll let you figure out how to use `--slurpfile` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although I figured out how to use --slurpfile and was able to get desired output